# Remove/change style of evince's red borders around links

Tags: pdf, pdf-reader, styles, border

Are you aware of a possibility to change the border size/color of the bold red border, evince paints around links (for example in PDF files, that have clickable links in the table of contents). Or is there even a possibility to remove them?

Answer (score 1):

See [this launchpad bug comment](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/evince/+bug/156643/comments/9) to fix this issue

```
\usepackage[pdftex, pdfborderstyle={/S/U/W 0}]{hyperref} % this disables the boxes around links
```

Answer (score 0):

This issue has been reported in Ubuntu's [Launchpad bug 156643](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/evince/+bug/156643) and [Gnome Bugzilla bug 503087](https://bugzilla.gnome.org/show_bug.cgi?id=503087).

Answer (score 0):

It seems that those red borders come from the LaTex template the author used, meaning evince is doing it's job by rendering it with those ugly colors. [This answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/1039430) suggests the same.

**My solution:** Print to file.

Those borders get stripped out when printing. If you print to a file, the resulting PDF will not have those borders.